# Moving function from view to controller Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to figure out how to move a lot of logic from view into controller/model.

(I think it's supposed to go in the model?)

**Show.html.erb**

```
 <div class="collectionList">
    <% @user.collections.each do |d| %>
      <%= d.name %> 
      Distinct Cards: <%= d.card_collections.count %> <br />
      Total Cards: 
        <% d.card_collections.each do |x| %>
        <% y = [] %>
        <% y << x.card_counts %>
        <% y.flatten! %>
        <% y = y.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x } %>
        <%= y %>
        <% end %>
      <% if d.public %> Public <% end %><br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Every user has a collection, which each collection can have a card_collection, which each of those can have a card.

The amount of 'card_collections' is the amount of distinct cards in your deck.
The sum of "card_collections.card_counts" is the total amount of cards. I'm thinking if I def it as 'sum of cards' and 'count of cards' in the model I can call it like that but I'm not sure how.

I also think my logic would be easier if I could move it into the model since I could use pluck/sum to get the results faster?

**Collection**

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :card_collections
  has_many :cards, through: :card_collections

  # validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Card**

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :card_collections
    has_many :collections, through: :card_collections
    belongs_to :deck, optional: true
end
```

**CardCollection**

```
class CardCollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :card
end
```

Comment: can you please explain relationships between tables(in has-many belongs-to structure), show method in controller and fields in model.

Answer (score 0):

Here, just add following code in your controller:

```
@user = User.joins(:collections).where("ANY CONDITION").select("*,count(collections.id) as card_collections_count, sum(collections.card_counts) as card_counts")
```

In your view file,

```
 <div class="collectionList">
    <% @user.each do |d| %>
      <%= d.name %> 
      Distinct Cards: <%= d.card_collections_count %> <br />
      Total Cards: <%= d.card_counts %>
      <% if d.public %> Public <% end %><br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: I assumed it was user controller so I added your query but now get
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: collections.card_counts: SELECT *,count(collections.id) as card_collections_count, sum(collections.card_counts) as card_counts FROM "users" INNER JOIN "collections" ON "collections"."user_id" = "users"."id"`

In reply. I've also tried `@users = User.joins(:collections, :card_collections).select("*,count(card_collections.id) as card_collections_count, sum(card_collections.card_counts) as card_counts")` and it errors on joining.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on your `CardCollection` model as

```
class CardCollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :card

  def sum_of_cards
    y = []
    y << self.card_counts
    y.flatten!
    y = y.inject(0) { |sum, self| sum + self }
    return y
  end
end
```

then call it in your view

```
<div class="collectionList">
  <% @user.collections.each do |d| %>
    <%= d.name %> 
    Distinct Cards: <%= d.card_collections.count %> <br />
    Total Cards: 
      <% d.card_collections.each do |x| %>
        <%= x.sum_of_cards %>
      <% end %>
    <% if d.public %> Public <% end %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to use the *[Sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum)* function to leverage the information.

```
<div class="collectionList">
    <% @user.collections.each do |d| %>
      <div class="collectionSample">
        <strong><%= link_to d.name, {:controller => "collections", :action => "show", :id => d.id } %></strong><br />
        Distinct Cards: <%= d.card_collections.count %> <br />
        Total Cards: <%= d.card_collections.sum(:card_counts) %>
        <% if d.public %> Public <% end %><br />
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```